# Sort in increasing order by deleting the minimum value each time loop finds the next minimum

Tags: vba

I currently am trying to make a code on VBA that would sort my values in an increasing order. After my program finds the minimum value and adds it to another column the column "B" , I wanted to make the cell of the minimum disappear in order to find my new minimum and enter it to the column "B" right under the initial value. Here is my code. For some reason  it wont delete the cell and gives me a "Object required error" . Please help

```
Option Explicit
Sub decreasing()
Dim a As Range, b As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Long
Dim minimum As Long

n = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

i = 1

While Cells(i, "A") <> ""
i = i + 1
For i = 1 To n

  Set a = Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(n, "A"))

Cells(i, "B") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(a)

Application.Min(a).Cells.Delete



   Next i
Wend


End Sub
```

Comment: `Min()` returns a value, not a range object. You'd need to use Find() or Match() to locate the cell with the Minimum value and then delete it.  You might find it easier to use `Application.Small(a, i)` inside your loop: then you wouldn't need to delete the cells you've already copied.

Comment: Also you'll want to decide whether you want to use the early-bound `Application.WorksheetFunction.Min` or the late-bound `Application.Min` function. Consistency please!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: You guys are awesome Thank you

Comment: @Csanogo notice the hollow checkmark next to Tim's answer - you can click it to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`Min()` returns a value, not a range object. You'd need to use `Find()` or `Match()` to locate the cell with the Minimum value and then delete it. You might find it easier to use `Application.Small(a, i)` inside your loop: then you wouldn't need to delete the cells you've already copied

```
Sub decreasing()

    Dim a As Range, b As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim n As Long
    Dim minimum As Long

    n = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set a = Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, "A"), Sheet1.Cells(n, "A"))

    For i = 1 To Application.Count(a)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, "B").Value = Application.Small(a, i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

since you're sorting don't reinvent the wheel and use [`Sort()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx) method of `Range` object:

```
Sub decreasing2()        
    With Sheet1
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(Rows.COUNT, 1).End(xlUp))
            .Offset(, 1).Value = .Value
            .Offset(, 1).Sort key1:=Range("B1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes '
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```